# How to access keys of an object dynamically inside angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a list using ng-repeat like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Myctrl.data"> {{Myctrl.resources.key}}</li>
```

Myctrl.data will look somthing like this:

```
{
personal : 
    {a: 100, b: 120}, 
professional : 
    { a: 320, b : 410}
}
```

Now in MyCtrl I have some mappings in `resources` object for each of the keys obtained from ng-repeat and I want to get the values of these keys and put it in list items.

```
$scope.resources = {
    personal: "Personal Details",
    professional: "Professional Details",
    freelance: "Freelance Details",
    custom: "Custom Details"
}
```

So when my ng-repeat is executed, I will get `personal, professional` etc and I want to substitute the values from `resources` object in my HTML.

How can I replace `key` in `{{Myctrl.resources.key}}` with actual value of key obtained in ng-repeat.

Comment: What keys does Myctrl.data contains? and can u explain what you exactly need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Myctrl.data">{{Myctrl.resources[key]}}</li>
```

Comment: I am not looking for this. I want to take the key and access a value from resources object which has the same key.

Comment: Sry, my bad! Try the below one...
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Myctrl.data">{{Myctrl.resources[key]}}</li>

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Myctrl.data"> {{resources.key}}</li>
```

will produces output list items as

```
Personal Details
Professional Details
```

Because in your repeat will produces

```
firsttime key is personal 
    {{resources.personal}} => Personal Details
secondtime key is professional
    {{resources.professional}} => Professional Details
```

**This is how it works exactly, what you actually looking for is this only?**

Comment: Did you even test this code? This is exactly what I have written. It doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah it wont work that's why i changed it {{Myctrl.resources.key}} to {{resources.key}}

Comment: Its an instance variable from controller. There is nothing as resources. We can actually access using keys instead of dot notation. That does the trick.